# asp.net 4 change selected menuitem color

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, vb.net

The menuitem's background color of asp.net 4 (developed via Visual Studio 2010)can't be change after be selected (I want the selected menuitem's background color is YellowGreen). I google this issue and try all ways found from internet. But they don't work. The menu is in a master file and uses the project's default menu css style:

```
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>                       
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Statistics.aspx" Text="Statistics"/>

                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Change.aspx" Text="Change"/>

                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="HistoryData.aspx" Text="History Data" />

                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="ChangePassword.aspx" Text="Change Password"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

The menu css in Site.css is

```
 div.hideSkiplink
 {
   background-color:#3a4f63;
   width:100%;
 }

 div.menu
 {
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /*padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;*/
 }

div.menu ul
{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #465c71;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 2.0em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size:medium;
}

 div.menu ul li a:hover
 {
  background-color: #bfcbd6;
  color: #465c71;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color:#ADFF2F;
color:White;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I can see the color change when I click a menuitem but the color is back to dark blue after release the mouse button. I tried change its static selected/dynamic selected style; change the menuitem's select status as true in MenuItemClick event; add selected css style;etc. But the selected menuitem's back color can't be changed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use following style:

```
a:active{background-color:color;}
```